# For Loop is not running properly

Tags: java, for-loop

Situation with the code is I think that the for loop in the private method is not getting int[] userArray. I have spent hours trying to figure out why the for loop is not working, I even tried using while loop.

```
public class Arrays {

  static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  private static int sizeOfArrayWanted;
  private static double average = 0;
  /**
   * private static int smallestNumber=1;
   * 
   * private static int count = 0; private static int total=0; private static
   * int average=total/count; private static int largestNumber=0; private static
   * int standardDeviation=0; private static int meanOfSD=0; private static int
   * x1=0; private static int[] userArray= new int [0];
   **/
  private static int total1 = 0;
  private static int standardDeviation = 0;
  private static int finalAverage = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // int randomNumber = (int)((Math.random() * 9) + 1);

    System.out.println("Hello how big would you like the array?");
    int sizeOfArrayWanted = scan.nextInt();
    int smallestNumber = 1;
    int largestNumber = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int standardDeviation = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int[] userArray = new int[sizeOfArrayWanted];
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeOfArrayWanted; x++) {

      userArray[x] = (int) ((Math.random() * 9) + 0);
      total = total + userArray[x];
      count++;
      if (userArray[x] < smallestNumber) {
        smallestNumber = userArray[x];
      }
      if (userArray[x] > largestNumber) {
        largestNumber = userArray[x];
      }
      System.out.print(userArray[x] + ", ");

      average = total / count;

    }

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("largest Number= " + largestNumber);
    System.out.println("smallest Number= " + smallestNumber);
    System.out.println("average =" + (total / count));

    Arrays.computeStandardDeviation(userArray, sizeOfArrayWanted);
  }

  private static int computeStandardDeviation(int[] userArray, int sizeofArrayWanted) {

    int x1 = 0;
    while (x1 < sizeofArrayWanted) {
      x1++;
      userArray[x1] = (int) (userArray[x1] - average);
      userArray[x1] = (int) Math.pow(userArray[x1], 2);
      total1 = total1 + userArray[x1];
      finalAverage = total1 / x1;
      standardDeviation = (int) Math.sqrt(finalAverage);
    }

    return standardDeviation;
  }
}
```

When I try to compile the program, I get the following errors:
Exception in thread "main" largest Number= 6
smallest Number= 1
average =4

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at Arrays.computeStandardDeviation(Arrays.java:80)
    at Arrays.main(Arrays.java:67)
```

Comment: define: `Not working`?

Comment: The private method runs, the for loop however cannot start at all.

Comment: The while loop is the problem: call `x1++;`at the end of the loop!

Comment: @BabanFaraj what he said ^. Your for loop is working fine... its your `computeStrandard....` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **increment** x1 after the check. Making it 1 too large for array at last iteration. Move x1++ into average calculation.

```
 while(x1<sizeofArrayWanted)
            {
          //  x1++;

     finalAverage = total1 / ++x1;
```

Comment: If I add x++ to the end of the loop I will get an error again, because I am trying to divide by 0 in order to get the average value.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at Arrays.computeStandardDeviation(Arrays.java:82)
 at Arrays.main(Arrays.java:67)

Comment: It says I have to wait 4mins

Answer (score 0):

Array index out of bounds exception is because you are incrementing `x1` before doing operations, rather you should do all operations and increment `x1` at the end. Otherwise, at the last iteration of the loop, you will be accessing an element outside the scope of the array.

```
private static int computeStandardDeviation(int[] userArray, int sizeofArrayWanted) {
    int x1 = 0;
    while (x1 < sizeofArrayWanted) {
        userArray[x1] = (int) (userArray[x1] - average);
        userArray[x1] = (int) Math.pow(userArray[x1], 2);
        total1 = total1 + userArray[x1];
        finalAverage = total1 / x1;
        standardDeviation = (int) Math.sqrt(finalAverage);

        x1++; //Increment should be done after all operations
    }

    return standardDeviation;
}
```

Also you dont need to pass the size parameter explicitly here, since you can just get the size from the array passed to the method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from the `computeStandardDeviation` method. The index starts at 0, so increasing it immediately will cause it not to look at the first spot in the array and therefore also check the `last index + 1` location.  It should be like this

```
private static int  computeStandardDeviation(int [] userArray, int sizeofArrayWanted)
{
    int x1=0;
    while(x1<sizeofArrayWanted)
    {
        userArray[x1]=(int) (userArray[x1]-average);
        userArray[x1]=(int) Math.pow(userArray[x1], 2);
        total1=total1+userArray[x1];
        finalAverage=total1/x1;
        standardDeviation= (int) Math.sqrt(finalAverage);

        x1++; // move this here
    }

    return standardDeviation;
}
```

Comment: Division by zero in total1/x1 - had me fooled as well

Comment: His issue (going from the error) is from an array out of bounds.. I did not look to find other issues